# Accessing Array Elements which are objects in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, element

I'm having some trouble figuring out if it is possible to access the elements of an array which has been set as the object of a string key in a dictionary. So for example, if I had a setup as below with each array giving me a list of books and the dictionary keys representing categories of books:

```
NSArray * list1= @[@"Book1",@"Book2",@"Book3"];  
NSArray * list2= @[@"Book4",@"Book5",@"Book6"];
NSArray * list3= @[@"Book7",@"Book8",@"Book9"];  
NSDictionary * libraryDict = @{@"category1": list1,@"category2":list2, @"category3":list3};
```

How would I access the individual elements of the array through the dictionary? Is that possible?

What I would hope to do would be to pick a random entry for the books lists once a key has been selected. So if a user decided that they wanted a random book recommendation from *category1* then I could generate a random selection from the *list1* array.

I am just beginning with Objective C so apologies if this is a n00b question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible,

For eg. For list1 array fetch like that below:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[libraryDict objectForKey:category1]);
```

If you want to access the individual element of category1 then try below:

```
for(NSString str in [libraryDict objectForKey:category1])
{
 NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Comment: Now that will display all the elements in the array category1 and that I have no problem with. But, how do I access the individual elements within category1?

Answer (score 0):

You can write :

```
NSArray *value = (NSArray *)libraryDict[@"category1"];
```

It will return the value paired to the key "`@"category1"`" (in your case, the NSArray "`list1`").